# Rowspan not working as expected in a table

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here][1]

This is the table I'm working on, and there are some issues with rowspan, and colspan. Can anyone know how to fix this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0hDK.png

And this is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<table>
    <style> td, th {
  padding: 0.9rem;
  
}
table {
    border-spacing: 10px;


}
table, td, th {
  border: 2.8px solid black;

}

tbody th { text-align:center; color:white; font-family: Georgia; }
tbody td { text-align:center; color:black; font-family: Georgia; }
</style>
  <tr>
<th rowspan="3" bgcolor="purple">Primary</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" bgcolor="purple">Secondary</th>
<th rowspan="2" bgcolor="purple">ICGSE</th>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="purple">Lower Secondary</th><th bgcolor="purple">Upper Secondary</th>
</tr>
    <td bgcolor="lavender">Myanmar</td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="lavender">English</td>
    <td bgcolor="lavender">English ICGSE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="lavender">Art and Design</td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="lavender">Mathematics</td>
    <td bgcolor="lavender">Mathemtics ICGSE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="lavender">Science</td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="lavender">  </td>
    <td bgcolor="lavender">Business ICGSE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all... you're missing a lot of valid HTML. I don't see an opening body tag. You have some `tbody` styles, but you're not using them. You have `<style></style>` tags inside your `<table>` tag. You need to declare styles before that tag is initialized. Can you clean this up first?

Comment: The second `tr` Tag is not closed, Plesse also fix that.